# How to get the exact location where a value from a symmetric matrix is above a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance, solver

I have multiple symmetric matrics of different lengths, I wanna get the index of the value that is above a threshold

Example

```
score = [array([[1.        , 0.01279797],
        [0.01279797, 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.03574311],
        [0.03574311, 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.0239954 , 0.02817505],
        [0.0239954 , 1.        , 0.99474305],
        [0.02817505, 0.99474305, 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.36028866, 0.04977658],
        [0.36028866, 1.        , 0.3766213 ],
        [0.04977658, 0.3766213 , 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.01812659],
        [0.01812659, 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.06357861, 0.03934581, 0.04123461],
        [0.06357861, 1.        , 0.28277748, 0.09248888],
        [0.03934581, 0.28277748, 1.        , 0.47969105],
        [0.04123461, 0.09248888, 0.47969105, 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.03861763],
        [0.03861763, 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.24099389],
        [0.24099389, 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.86898379],
        [0.86898379, 1.        ]]), array([[1.        , 0.18477927],
        [0.18477927, 1.        ]])]
```

I get the triangle above by

```
import numpy as np
data = [] 
longest  = 100
for k in range(longest):   
  for i in range(len(score)):
    if len(score[i])==k: 
      data.extend(score[i][np.triu_indices(score[i].shape[0], k = 1)])    

x = np.array(data)
df1= np.where(x > 0.995)
```

df1 return the index inside data but I want to go back and get the index in the matrix

is that possible ?

I need a way to extract it, so for matrices (2*2) it is easy since the upper triangle is one number, but when a matrix is of more than 3**3 I don't know how to solve it

Comment: So for each matrix you want the x,y coordinates of the upper triangle that is above a threshold?

Comment: yes, if an upper triangle has a value > the threshold, I want the x,y of the corresponding value inside the matrix

Comment: example is not helping, could you provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I added an aexample of the matrics and I want the location inside the matrix where the value is >0.95